# Testing font file for errors in Linux

Tags: fonts, kerning, linux

I've produced this font and for some strange reason the kerning table only works partially on *one* of my Linux boxes. It works on 2 other Linux boxes for some reason. I'm wondering if there is a way to test the file for errors or things that might trip up some Linux distros.

It works in one of my Ubuntu 16.04s, a Ubuntu 14.04 but doesn't work on another Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, n/m. It turned out that one system was *generating* bad font files, not *reading* them improperly. I guess it's a bug in the font generating software.